# Constructor error, setter not working(Solidity)

Tags: constructor, solidity, setter, nft

I was working on my smart contract project and when I put **some values** at the depolyment of the contract as inputs and I got an error of saying.

**"revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the
value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information."**

And my code is

```
uint[] private Info;

function SetInfo(uint[] memory data) private onlyOwner{
Info = new uint[](data.length);
for(uint i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
  Info[i] = data[i];
}


constructor(uint[] memory _Info,uint[] memory _SecondInfo)
ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
SetInfo(_Info);
SetSecondInfo(_SecondInfo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to adjust your smart contract. I put some comments that will help you to understand what I did and your errors in original smart contract.
Smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

// Your class must  inheritance ERC721 smart contract, if you want to use its functions
contract Test is ERC721 {
    uint[] private Info;
    // Specify variable that will contain  owner address when contract will create.
    address owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't the owner!");
        _;
    }

    // You must to give a name and symbol about your ERC721 token
    constructor(uint[] memory _Info, uint[] memory _SecondInfo) ERC721("TESTToken", "TST") {
        // Set owner variable with msg.sender value 
        owner = msg.sender;
        SetInfo(_Info);
        SetSecondInfo(_SecondInfo);
    } 

    function SetInfo(uint[] memory data) private onlyOwner {
        Info = new uint[](data.length);
        for(uint i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
            Info[i] = data[i];
        }
    }

    function SetSecondInfo(uint[] memory data) private onlyOwner {
        // your logic
    }
}
```